# Is A and C NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, decision-problem

Given 3 decision problems in $NP$: $A,B,C$.
Consider that there are $2$ reduction algorithms, one is $A\le_p B$ (with run-time $n^{10}$) and the other is $B\le_p C$ (with run-time $n^5$).

If $B$ is $NP-complete$, is it valid to say that $A$ and $C$ are also $NP-complete$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if we reduce problem $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ in polynomial time, formally $\mathcal{A}\le_p \mathcal{B}$, then we can conclude that, $\mathcal{B}$ is at least hard as $\mathcal{A}$, so according to your question, we can't conclude that $\mathcal{A}$ should be NP-Complete, because it can be member of $\mathcal{P}$. But because of $\mathcal{B}\le_p \mathcal{C}$, we can say that $\mathcal{C}$ is at least NP-Complete.

Answer (score 0):

Only $C$ will be $NP-complete$

To say that a language $L$ is $NP-complete$, you need two things:

1. $L\in NP$
2. $L\in NP-hard$

The reductions $A\le_p B\le_p C$ will guarantee you that:

1. $A\in NP$, but it won't guarantee that $A\in NP-hard$
2. $C\in NP-hard$, and since we assumed it was in $NP$ as well then $C\in NP-complete$

Hence, we cannot conclude that $A$ $NP-complete$, but we can say that $C$ is.